# Sencha Touch Charts style

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-theming

I'm playing with Sencha Touch Charts. I've got them working, with interactions, animation everything is good. I even styled a bunch of them.

But when I got around styling a series of type area.. it just wouldn't take.

```
new Ext.chart.Chart({
    theme: 'MyTheme',
    cls: 'myClass',
    legend: { ... },
    interactions: [{ ... }],
    store: app.stores.MyStore,

    axes: [...],

    series: [{ type: 'area', axis: 'left', xField: 'Date', yField: 'someField' },
             { type: 'line', axis: 'right', xField: 'Date', yField: 'someField2' }
    ]
})
```

and the style

```
chart[cls=myClass] {

series {
         &[type=area] {
             fill: #FFA500;
         }

      &[type=line] {
          stroke: #008000;
      fill: #008000;
      marker {
          stroke: #008000;
          fill: #008000;
      }
      }
    }
 }
```

so the line series is styled just fine, but the area is not :| Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I've not actually tried this but it looks like you're almost there...

Based on the example found at http://docs.sencha.com/touch-charts/1-0/#!/guide/touch_charts_styling (at "axis" -> "label")

I'd try:

```
axis[position=bottom] {
      label {
          rotate: 0 0 45;
      }
  }
```

Comment: My problem would be with --- &[type=area] {fill: #FFA500;} --- the rotation works just fine!